# Trying to get hour int from time string but getting this error in c++

Tags: c++, string, time, type-conversion, integer

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int h;
        string s1;
        getline(cin,s1);
        cout<<s1;
        h=10*(s1[0]-'0')+1*(s1[1]-'0');
        cout<<h;
    }
}
```

I gave below as input

```
1
11:01 PM
```

got this as output

```
-560
```

I want to convert the hour part of the time from string to int.

Comment: Relevant (possibly a duplicate): [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/580083)

Comment: This is a great chance to use a debugger to step through line by line and examine your variables in order to narrow down exactly which part does something you don't expect and what exactly it does.

Comment: This resolved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int h;
        string s1;
        getline(std::cin.ignore(), s1);
        //getline(cin,s1);
        cout<<s1 << endl;
        h=10*(s1[0]-'0')+1*(s1[1]-'0');
        cout<<h << endl;
    }
}
```

I highly encourage you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) to understand what makes the difference.